# Import Numerous Modules

Tags: python

I'm working on my making a simple tester for my project, my project is a group of many self contained python files (e.g. solution1.py, solution2.py, etc.). My tester works, but it requires me to do `import solution1, solution2, ...`, how can I just import everything that matches a pattern?

I have tried creating a list of the files using glob and importing the list, but that gave:

```
ImportError: No module named solutions
```

I tried to eval() it, but that was 'invalid syntax'.

Perhaps the question is, how can I interpolate a list of strings into a list of modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import a module identified by a string with the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) module:

```
import importlib

list_of_module_names = ...
for s in list_of_module_names:
    importlib.import_module(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `importlib.import_module()` to import a module named by a string.

If you wanted to construct an import statement instead, you'd need to use `exec()` instead of `eval()`. The latter can only evaluate expressions; the former executes statements.